# How to check if a user is admin of their Google Apps domain in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, openid, google-apps

I followed [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_python_gae.html) to enable single sign on for an app that installs through the Google Apps Marketplace. Now, what is the best way to check if the user is admin of the Google Apps domain?

**Edit:** I'm asking this because we can define links for "setup" and "manage" in the [manifest](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/manifest.html). I don't think those pages in my app should be accessible by *all* users of the Google Apps domain, only by the *admin* ones. And then I thought I'd just need to limit access to those pages based on who is admin of the domain.

Comment: What do you mean "admin of their app"? Do you mean "admin of their domain"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take your admin user to your app via the [optional step3](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/lifecycle.html#step3) of the install process from the marketplace where you could manually request which user(s) they want to dedicate admin rights to within your app.

Comment: Following this idea, I'd have to assume the first user to access the "setup" page would be the admin. This is a little rough because the user is not forced to complete that step. Which means: an admin could miss the text asking to complete the step and then any user would be able to do it and take control of the app.

Comment: Forget what I said. I just tried it and the admin is required to setup it. That's it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably could use the Provisioning API to do [retrieve](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_developers_protocol.html#Retrieve_Account_Example) a user account. In the [response](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_developers_protocol.html#Sample_UserEntry_Response) you would then be able to tell whether a user is admin or not:

```
 <apps:login userName="JoeBloggs" suspended="false" admin="false"
    changePasswordAtNextLogin="false" agreedToTerms="true"/>
```

[edit] I see you can use the gdata-python-client [library](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference_python.html) to call a `RetrieveUser` function to make things even easier.

Comment: This implies that the OP's application would have to request ProvisioningAPI access in the manifest. It might be quite a leap asking users of your app to give you access to one of the most powerful APIs available just to check if they are the admin.

Comment: Also, if the Google Apps domain is not premium, I wouldn't even be able to use Provisioning API on their domain, right?

Comment: I believe you can get *read-only* provisioning API access if you are using the marketplace

Comment: Yes, Marketplace apps get read-only access to the API.
Yes, it might be a big ask for users to allow access to the Provisioning API, but I guess the OP's application is already quite deeply embedded into the domain if he needs to know whether a user is admin or not.

Comment: Thanks tomlong, you're answer was very helpful and I'd choose it too if I could choose two. I'll end using the Provisioning API too, but for this case the setup step was enough for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `users.is_current_user_admin()`?

Comment: Oh that won't work. `users.is_current_user_admin()` checks the *App Engine* admin (me!), but I want to know if the user that installed my app is admin of their Google Apps domain.